# Java enumeration with composite values

Tags: java, enums

Is it proper to have an enumeration with composite values like:

```
private enum SomeEnum {
    A, B, A_AND_B, NEITHER;
}
```

I feel like it should have an XOR-like logic, should only contain basic unit values. If somehow it is needed to use A & B together, it should be in a `List<SomeEnum>`. Is my thinking correct, or faulty. Can you give me some details on this?

Comment: Yes, a `Set<SomeEnum>` seems better suited for combinations.

Comment: Or even a `EnumSet<>` that has useful static functions like `EnumSet.of(SomeEnum.A,SomeEnum.B)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for details about why it would be more proper to use one approach or another.  That depends on what you plan to do with the enum in question and whether it's likely to change.

If it's possible that one day there will be other choices besides `A` and `B`, then it's clearly more "proper" to go with a Set (an EnumSet being the most efficient implementation as others here have pointed out), because otherwise you may be creating a future bug.

Otherwise, for the specific case you cite, the principle which applies might be [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it). Do it the simplest way, and improve it when you have the time.

More generally, there are issues of complexity and readability of the code. I don't think using a `Set` makes the code more readable if there are only 4 possibilities, and it makes it a bit less simple (especially if the values have to be passed to and from a database).

However, if there are many more values than just `A` and `B`, then the `Set` approach is clearly superior. The `Set` approach has the advantage that the complexity of the code doesn't increase with the number of possible values.  On the other hand, spelling out all combinations in the enum becomes increasingly, explosively messy with each additional value (factorial order of increase in the number of combinations), with increasing risk of erors of omission. And if you want to associate data with each enum value, passed in via a constructor, it becomes even messier.

Comment: There are only A & B actually. The choice is between A_AND_B & NEITHER or a `Set` of A & B. So for small enumeration classes, using `Set` method is a bit too much, though I still like it more. This enum is a bridge between client and another enum in DB that does not have those compound or absent values.

Comment: So in your specific case, it looks like YAGNI applies.  Again, it depends on what you want to do with the enum, but for most uses an enum with 4 options seems simpler than using a Set and 2 options.

Comment: That might be true, since it will also affect the RS of my API, since I will return a list rather than a single enum, which will make the code of client extra messy... Thanks for the detailed response

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` to represent combinations of elements. You're right that the enum should only contain the "atoms".

`List` is probably not appropriate as you usually don't care about ordering of these elements.

Also note that Java provides [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) as a memory-efficient `Set` implementation for enums.